# Expanding an array along particular dimension

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I have an array as below:

```
arr = np.arange(2*1*15).reshape(2, 1, 15)
```

Now, how can I expand this array to shape `(2, 10, 15)`. To fill in the values it'd be okay to use the same values as in the `(1, 15)` part of the original array (i.e. from the last two dimensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to duplicate the values along the second axis:

```
np.repeat(arr, 10, axis=1).shape
# (2, 10, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I figured out that [numpy.broadcast_to](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) can also do this job.

As a small contrived example:

```
In [8]: np.broadcast_to(arr, (2, 5, 15))
Out[8]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])
```

---

**Note on performance**: After timing it, I found out that `numpy.broadcast_to` is ca. **40x** faster when compared to `numpy.repeat`.
The [reason for this performance gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304689/expanding-an-array-along-particular-dimension/55304842?noredirect=1#comment97340639_55304842) is because:

> It's faster because it creates a read-only view of the data with lots of elements pointing to the same memory locations. If you copy the result, the performance is about the same. If you don't need to edit the final result, it provides a massive performance gain

Comment: It's faster because it creates a read-only view of the data with lots of elements pointing to the same memory locations.  If you `copy` the result, the performance is about the same.  If you don't need to edit the final result, it provides a massive performance gain